# Select best fit transaction combination in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, combinatorics, bitcoin

I need to select best bitcoin transaction combination for sending. I achieved result using PHP, but it uses a lot of memory and there is huge possibility that database will handle that better.

Whole list of transactions:

```
+------------------+------+--------+
|  Transaction ID  | Vout | Amount |
+------------------+------+--------+
| transactionid1   |    0 | 10     |
| transactionid1   |    1 | 1.5    |
| transactionid2   |    0 | 0.5    |
| transactionid3   |    0 | 0.7    |
+------------------+------+--------+
```

I need to create some kind of function or select query which will return me following row when i provide amount = 0.4

```
+------------------+------+--------+
|  Transaction ID  | Vout | Amount |
+------------------+------+--------+
| transactionid2   |    0 | 0.5    |
+------------------+------+--------+
```

When i provide amount = 2.1

```
+------------------+------+--------+
|  Transaction ID  | Vout | Amount |
+------------------+------+--------+
| transactionid1   |    1 | 1.5    |
| transactionid3   |    0 | 0.7    |
+------------------+------+--------+
```

So it's kind of [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with leftover. Here is how i resolved my problem using combinatorics. I've flatten transaction data into $key => $value array, where $key is transactionid_vout and value is amount.

```
$flatterTransactions = array(4) (
  [transactionid1_0] => (int) 10
  [transactionid1_1] => (float) 1.5
  [transactionid2_0] => (float) 0.5
  [transactionid3_0] => (float) 0.7
)
```

Then i create combinations from that transactions

```
$combinations = array(15) (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_0] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_1] => 1.5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [transactionid2_0] => 0.5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [transactionid3_0] => 0.7
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_0] => 10
            [transactionid1_1] => 1.5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_0] => 10
            [transactionid2_0] => 0.5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_0] => 10
            [transactionid3_0] => 0.7
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_1] => 1.5
            [transactionid2_0] => 0.5
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_1] => 1.5
            [transactionid3_0] => 0.7
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [transactionid2_0] => 0.5
            [transactionid3_0] => 0.7
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_0] => 10
            [transactionid1_1] => 1.5
            [transactionid2_0] => 0.5
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_0] => 10
            [transactionid1_1] => 1.5
            [transactionid3_0] => 0.7
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_0] => 10
            [transactionid2_0] => 0.5
            [transactionid3_0] => 0.7
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_1] => 1.5
            [transactionid2_0] => 0.5
            [transactionid3_0] => 0.7
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [transactionid1_0] => 10
            [transactionid1_1] => 1.5
            [transactionid2_0] => 0.5
            [transactionid3_0] => 0.7
        )

)
```

Then i go through combinations and create summed combination array with scoring. Scoring goal here is to use less transactions.

```
$summedCombinations[$key] = array(
                'sum' => $sum,
                'count' => count($combination),
                'score' => $sum * (count($combination) * 2)
            );
```

After all i filter array by sum field to leave only transactions which cover my amount. Order by score and receiving best match.

Comment: The problem with your algo is creating every possible configuration even though a problem might have been solved in a previous step.

Comment: @JakubKania can you share a solution, or a hint?

Comment: this article may help you http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/02/22/and-now-for-a-completely-inappropriate-use-of-sql-server/

Comment: @message That is a hint. I'm afraid db ain't exactly the correct place for computing (although it's possible) since from the start you're gonna operate on the same set of data. At best you can write a SP to pull desired data since you want a) exact match OR b) all the values smaller than the desired one + the smallest one that is bigger than desired value. In the code logic instead of creating all possible combinations try to eliminate doubles and stop combinations when they are bigger than desired value (if you need 5.0 there's no point in combining the 10.0 combination further).

Answer (score 0):

Best is a bit problematic here, but here's how I would go about it. No matter how you do it, you have to deal with an algorithm for selecting the combination.

```
 WITH target AS (select ? as target),
 RECURSIVE largest_txs AS (
      select transaction_id, vout, amount, amount as running_total
        from transactions
  CROSS JOIN target 
       where amount < target.target
    order by amount desc limit 1
   UNION ALL
      SELECT t.transaction_id, t.vout, t.amount, t.amount + l.running_total
        FROM transactions
        JOIN (select * from largest_txs order by amount asc limit 1) l
  CROSS JOIN target 
       WHERE amount < target.target + l.running_total AND t.transaction_id NOT IN
             (select transaction_id from largest_txs)
 )
 SELECT transaction_id, vout, amount, running_total FROM largest_txs
  UNION
 SELECT t.transaction_id, t.vout, t.amount, null
   FROM transactions t 
  WHERE t.transaction_id NOT IN (select transaction_id from largest_txs)
  ORDER BY amount asc limit 1;
```

This should perform as well as can be expected.  You will definitely want an index on amount if the table gets to be of any size though.

Comment: Thanks, but i already solved my problem on PHP level. Btw combinatorics was really bad idea for that.